# Create a file on back-end, from the text coming from front-end

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, codemirror

I'm trying to make an app that grabs code from two different code editors (using `angular-ui-codemirror`), one for the code to be tested and the other for the test code, and outputs the output of the tests back onto the site.

As of now, I can get the text from both code editors concatenated and console.logged out in the browser.

I'm wondering how I could take that code and save it into a file on the back- end, so that I could spawn a child-process that runs tests on it and does something with the `stdout`.

I'm using `angular`, `node` and `express` for coding and for testing, I am using `mocha`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fs.writeFile('./yournewfile.js', newCode, function (error) {
  if (error) return callback(error)

  var Exec = require('child_process').exec;

  // change node to mocha if your newCode is mocha test code
  Exec('node ./yournewfile.js', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    // do something here
  })
})
```